# How to disable module in Magento Cloud

Tags: magento2

I have been looking for a way to disable a Magento module in a Magento Cloud Enterprise instance.

Whenever I run the `bin/magento module:disable` command, I get this error.

`Command line user does not have read and write permissions on generated directory.`

So how can I disable modules?

Comment: did you try with sudo?

Answer (score 0):

On Magento cloud you need run deploy process.

Anything that is related with file change (not  related with  cache).

You can use magento-cloud command. Create branch , disable module, test it and deploy to live.

https://devdocs.magento.com/cloud/reference/cli-ref-topic.html

https://devdocs.magento.com/cloud/reference/discover-deploy.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to set to '0' the module status ('Vendor_Module' => 0) in *app/etc/config.php* using the branch you want to update.

So add your changes, commit and push them.
A new deploy will start and you'll see the module disabled in the right environment.

Comment: Yes, but I need a quick way to disable module without deploying. Deployment takes a long time and I only need to check something then will enable the module again.

Comment: I don't think it's possible without any deployment. you need to deploy.